# Taken username: how can I have only one space at the end when suggesting an alternative username?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
name = raw_input("Enter username: ")
space = ' * '

print 'The username you have entered is taken. Do you want to change it to: '

for letter in name:
    print letter + space,
print ".",
```

I want to get only one space at the end between "*" and ".", for example: if the entered username is George, I want the output to be "G * e * o * r * g * e *[space]."

Currently I get "G * e * o * r * g * e *[space][space]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make use of [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> name = 'George'
>>> space = ' * '
>>> space.join(name) + ' * .'
'G * e * o * r * g * e * .'
```

If you need to use a `for` loop:

```
>>> result = ''
>>> for char in name:
...     result += char + space
... 
>>> result += '.'
>>> result
'G * e * o * r * g * e * .'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I have to use for loop. Is it possible with for loop?